# Windows 8 display driver on Asus EE PC flare series 1025

Tags: windows-8.1, display, netbook, display-driver, eee-pc

I have installed Windows 8.1 on `Asus` `ee pc flare series 1025`. Everything works fine except that fact that  display is working at resolution 600x800 and in `Computer Managment`  standart display adapter is shown. I was trying to download from Asus site and install display drivers wor `Windows 7`, but install told that it is wrong OS.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.exdir.blogspot.nl/2013/04/asus-eee-pc-flare-1025c-driver-win7-win8.html gives links to drivers. DL the video driver and unzip. 
Do not run setup.exe, instead install the driver manually from the device list, right click and browse to the driver directory you just downloaded.